# How to keep workspace variable values in memory?

Tags: matlab, function, variables, memory, temp

I have a workspace with a set of variables (e.g. `var1`, `var2`, `var3`, `var4`, `var5`, `var6` and `var7`). There is a .m function (using `assignin('base',...)` containing the defaults values for `var1` to `var7`. The user will open Matlab and run this function in order to have the variable and their default values added to the workspace. The user might after that change the values of some variables or even delete some variables.

Now, if the user has changed variable values and that he run the function again, i don't want the default value to overwrite the new value entered by the user.

Here what i have so far :

```
S = evalin('base','whos');
listWorkspaceVar = {S.name};
compareCellArrayList = ismember(listWorkspaceVar, listParam); % logical vector, listParam is the list of variables in the function assigning the default values, so here listParam would be = {'var1' 'var2' 'var3' 'var4' 'var5' 'var6' 'var7'})
if any(compareCellArrayList) % check if there is at least one declared variable in the base workspace
    tempWorkspaceVarVal = cell(sum(compareCellArrayList),2); % Pre-allocating, 1 column for the variable name and 1 column for the variable value
    jj = 1;
    for ii = 1:size(S,1)
        if compareCellArrayList(1, ii)
            tempWorkspaceVarVal(jj,:) = {listWorkspaceVar{1, ii}, ...
                                         evalin('base',listWorkspaceVar{1, ii})}; 
            jj = jj + 1;
        end
    end
    theDefaultValueFunction() % The function that assignin the default values
    cellfun(@(x,y) assignin('base', x, y), ...
            tempWorkspaceVarVal(:,1), tempWorkspaceVarVal(:,2)) % Overwrite with the temp values in order to keep the new entered values
end
```

If I don't want to change the function assignin the default values, is my method the best one to keep the new modified variable values?

Comment: You are over-constraining your question, which amounts to something like this: "I'm currently painting my house using a hammer, which I'd prefer to keep using.  To get enough paint to stick to the hammer, I wrapped it in duct tape.  Is this the best method?"  Your solution is, frankly, unreadable; not due to the code, but due to the design.  If it works for you, keep using it.  Otherwise, clarify what you mean by "best", and consider asking a broader question.

Comment: @Peter Well what if there is nothing available other than a hammer and duct tape for painting my house? There are reasons behind the design, that I didn't explain here to keep the question simpler. The function declaring default variable is actually ran by a popup field in a simulink mask. It is a function because the popup send the option selected as input. Does it help you?

Comment: OK, then if the code works, what is your question actually?  Is your code too slow?  Too large?  Doesn't work properly?  If it doesn't work, how does it fail?

Comment: @Peter It runs and everything work fine. But I have the feeling the method I used may be not the best solution, hence my question.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should not use a function for this, but a script. A script operates in the caller's workspace. So if it is called from the command line this is the base workbase. 
Another advantage is that you do not need `assignin`, which can be a real pain during debugging.

using the `exist('var1', 'var')` command you can check whether the variable `var1` already exists and therefore should not be (re-)initialized.

in meta matlab code:

```
if ~exist('var1', 'var')
    % var1 does not exist
    var1 = zeros(10, 5);
end
```

Comment: I like the idea. But like i said, I would prefer not having to change the function (or change it to a script).

Comment: In that case you should consider using `evalin`

Answer (score 1):

If you are cool with adding atleast just a few lines of code to theDefaultValueFunction(), then this is a crazy solution you can try:

```
function theDefaultValueFunction()

persistent hasRunOnce  % creates a empty matrix
if isempty(hasRunOnce) % Check if the function has already run
    % Your function code here
end
hasRunOnce = true;
```

After the first time the function is run, the hasRunOnce variable is set and the function does not change the workspace variables any more. [persistent variables](http://msenux.redwoods.edu/Math4Textbook/Programming/VariableScope.pdf) has local scope inside a function, but they are stored in memory like a global variable.

To clear the persistent variable you would have to clear the function:

```
clear theDefaultValueFunction
```

Comment: This could work, but how would you cope with the fact that a user might delete one of the variable (it needs to be declared again with the default value if he does)? Your solution is quite good if the user don't deleted a variable or more.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a function (that does not return) and which gets values from the base worskpace and also edits them, you will probably need [global variables](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/global.html).

However, think really hard whether you need this. Consider letting the function simply return the variables, or saving them to file. In general global variables are not recommended, but I would prefer them over your current approach.

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely not the best approach. But guess this is simple and will save a lot of time for you.

```
function theDefaultValueFunction()

save('workspace.mat') % save all of the workspace, save it in a place with write permissions

% your code here

load('workspace.mat') % updates the variables into their old values (i.e user changed values), 
                      % any new variables (recreated by the function) remain unaffected

delete workspace.mat
```